# Form to print inputs and textarea in the same page

Tags: javascript, php

I have this form that now sends the result to an e—mail.

```
<form action="https://formmail.servage.net/" method=POST>
<input type=hidden name="id" value="28939">
<input type=hidden name="subject" value="FORM SUBJECT"> 
<input type=text placeholder="E-Mail" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'E-Mail'" name="E-MAIL"><p> 
<input type=text placeholder="Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name'" name="NAME"><p> 
<input type=text placeholder="City" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'City'" name="CITY"><p> 
<textarea onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }" name="FEEDBACK" id=text rows=5 placeholder="Message" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Message'"></textarea> <br><br>
Push enter
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pdkox9ar/

All I want is to print the inputs and textarea in the same page at the bottom of the form. How's that possible?

Comment: @devpro I don't get your question, sorry.

Comment: Do you have any PHP code to show? You will find an example of form submission here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm (see *POST method*)

Comment: Do u want to print values by using Php???

Comment: Federico: I wrote out a suggested code outline [on your recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35682493/472495) to give you some pointers you appeared to need. Rather than respond with feedback and thanks, you deleted the post. Whilst the question was not a good fit here, nevertheless interacting with consideration and in a community-minded way is generally expected here - remember there are real people at the end of these avatars.

Comment: @halfer I just preferred to re—write the question with an example and better explaination. I know that here if you write "thanks" most of the time there's someone editing the question and removing that "Thanks". And I thank you for your effort, btw if you read better.

Comment: Yes, thanks is often removed from questions. But I am advocating against "grab and run" in the comments - where you see effort, reward it, if only through a simple response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you add a button to engage in extracting the values from your input fields - and also add a container div to show your text in, like so;

```
<button id="showme">showme</button><div id="output" />
```

You would need some javascript to loop over the input fields of your form, something similar to the following;

```
var button = document.getElementById('showme');
document.getElementById('showme').onclick = function showcontents() {
  var form = document.forms[0];
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    var input = form.elements[i];
    var value = input.value;
    var key = input.name;
    result += input.name + " = " + input.value + "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
};
```

I have not tested this in older browsers, where i believe textarea might not always have the `value` attribute.. Instead you extract contents via `innerHTML` on textarea's - but this is from memory alone. The above should work in html5 capable  browsers.

Comment: This works perfectly @mschr, just how can I keep the first result and add the new ones too?

Comment: .. not sure but does changing `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;` to *(+=)*  `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += result;` help?

Comment: IT WORKS @mschr! Now I just have to figure out how to keep those in the page also after refreshing :)

Comment: amuga3 gave half the answer to that question but its a bit of a different category then what you originally asked. Look into $_SESSION in PHP which is a 'carry over' for each browser that visits (persistent through cookies). Otherwise, you'd need a database to store previously sent emails and present user with these data

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="name" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

It will pass the form data to the same script, so at the top you can place you PHP to get that values.

```
if (isset($_POST ['E-Mail'])) {
    $email = $_POST ['E-Mail']; 
}
```

and to display on a page:

```
echo $email;
```

Comment: @Federico Ferrari Do you want to show form data below after the form submission or instantly during typing? I can give an idea how to do that on user side in javascript. Sorry, the question wasn't clear to me. Ignore, if you are happy with the current answer.